# Why does interpolating a const string result in a compiler error?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

Why does string interpolation in c# does not work with const strings? For example:

```
private const string WEB_API_ROOT = "/private/WebApi/";
private const string WEB_API_PROJECT = $"{WEB_API_ROOT}project.json";
```

From my point of view, everything is known at compile time. Or is that a feature that will be added later?

Compiler message:

> The expression being assigned to 'DynamicWebApiBuilder.WEB_API_PROJECT' must be constant.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interpolated strings are just converted to `string.Format` calls.

Comment: For a workaround, replace `const` with `static readonly`

Comment: @juharr: which does not really explain why the compiler could not check if the parameter you pass is another constant that could be used to initialize this constant. It is allowed with concatenated string literals. So why isnt it allowed with combined string literals, the compiler could use the same technique.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's what I'm talking about. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @BendEg: i think i know the answer. It has to do with implementation costs for a feature that has not much added value and works only with constants. You can always use `WEB_API_ROOT + "project.json"` or `static readonly` instead of `const`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that makes sense. But would be nice, because from my point of view this makes code more readable.

Comment: This kind of code would work in C++, but C# doesnt have compile time checks on methods and doesnt compile the results in if all parameters are known (not all C++ compilers do this? I'm not sure, but some do the least.) It's a really hard thing to implement and also very error prone and tbf for C# it doesnt really add too much value, thats why it isn't implemented yet probably.

Comment: Can't use static readonly when the string is being passed to a compile-time constraint like a SwaggerResponseAttribute.  Trying to set the Description property to a string that embeds a constant, and can't use the new $"" format, because it doesn't support constants. Lame.

Comment: As pointed out in @zvick's answer below, this is no longer an issue as of C# 10, when the "Constant Interpolated Strings" feature was added to the language: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/constant_interpolated_strings

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Interpolated strings are simply converted to calls to `string.Format`. So your above line actually reads

```
private const string WEB_API_PROJECT = string.Format("{0}project.json", WEB_API_ROOT);
```

And this is not compile time constant as a method call is included.

---

On the other hand, string *concatenation* (of simple, constant string literals) can be done by the compiler, so this will work:

```
private const string WEB_API_ROOT = "/private/WebApi/";
private const string WEB_API_PROJECT = WEB_API_ROOT + "project.json";
```

or switch from `const` to `static readonly`:

```
private static readonly string WEB_API_PROJECT = $"{WEB_API_ROOT}project.json";
```

so the string is initialized (and `string.Format` called) at the first access to any member of the declaring type.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That simple concationation is clear, just thought I also can use this new c# 6 feature here.

Comment: @Rene, Even using [private static readonly string ] , the compiler raise an error "The name 'WEB_API_ROOT' does not exist in the current context". The variable  'WEB_API_ROOT' should be defined in the same context.

Comment: @M.Hassan, you are making something wrong. It works for me.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, yes, I test using last version c#7.3 (vs 2017.9.2) and it's working `private static readonly string WEB_API_PROJECT = $"{WEB_API_ROOT}project.json"`, It seems that it may be resolved by Roslyn

Answer (score 32):

An additional explanation why string interpolation expressions are not considered constants is that *they are not constant*, even if all their inputs are constants. Specifically, they vary based on the current culture. Try executing the following code:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Console.WriteLine($"{3.14}");

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");

Console.WriteLine($"{3.14}");
```

Its output is:

```
3.14
3,14
```

Note that the output is different, even though the string interpolation expression is the same in both cases. So, with `const string pi = $"{3.14}"`, it wouldn't be clear what code should the compiler generate.

**UPDATE:** In C# 10/.Net 6, string interpolations that only contains `const` strings can be `const`. So the code in the question is not an error anymore.

Answer (score 6):

There is a discussion in Roslyn project at  [roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11259)  that finalize the following conclusion:

Read the excerpt:

> It's not a bug, it was explicitly designed to function like this. You not liking it doesn't make it a bug. 
>   String.Format isn't needed for concatenating strings, but that's not
>   what you're doing. 
>   You're interpolating them, and String.Format is
>   needed for that based on the spec and implementation of how
>   interpolation works in C#.
>
> If you want to concatenate strings, go
>   right ahead and use the same syntax that has worked since C# 1.0.
>   Changing the implementation to behave differently based on usage would
>   produce unexpected results:

```
  const string FOO = "FOO";
  const string BAR = "BAR";
  string foobar = $"{FOO}{BAR}";
  const string FOOBAR = $"{FOO}{BAR}"; // illegal today

  Debug.Assert(foobar == FOOBAR); // might not always be true
```

Even the statement:

```
  private static readonly string WEB_API_PROJECT = $"{WEB_API_ROOT}project.json";
```

The compiler raise an error:

```
 "The name 'WEB_API_ROOT' does not exist in the current context".
```

The variable 'WEB_API_ROOT' should be defined in the same context

So, for the question of OP: Why does string interpolation is not working with const strings?
Answer: It's by C# 6 specs. for more details read [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") -String Interpolation for C#](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570292)

Comment: Note that the takeaway here seems to be more or less this: It's possible to define (and set) a hypothetical default culture that modifies all formatted strings, which would change the return value of even `string.Format()` calls that consist of only `const` `string`s, **at runtime**. Since that culture check could happen, at best, during the static initializer, but the `const` string value set only happens at compiler time, a `const` interpolated string could become not equal to the value of the interpolated string at runtime, if the culture at compile time is not the culture at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

C# 10 (currently in preview at time of writing) will [include the ability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const) to use `const` interpolated strings, as long as the usage does not involve scenarios where culture may affect the outcome (such as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453393/393931)).

So if the interpolation is simply concatenating strings together, it will work at compile time.

```cs
const string Language = "C#";
const string Platform = ".NET";
const string Version = "10.0";
const string FullProductName = $"{Platform} - Language: {Language} Version: {Version}";
```

This is now allowed in VS 2019 version 16.9, if the `preview` language version is selected (set `<LanguageVersion>preview</LanguageVersion>` in your project file).

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2951#issuecomment-736722760

Answer (score 3):

in C# 9.0 or earlier we can not allow to use `const` with interpolated strings.
if you want to merge constant strings together, you will have to use concatenation and not interpolation.

```
const string WEB_API_ROOT = "/private/WebApi/";
const string WEB_API_PROJECT = WEB_API_ROOT + "project.json";
```

but from C# 10.0 Allow `const` interpolated strings as features and enhancements to the C# language.

C# 10.0 feature available in .NET 6.0 framework, in that we can able to use it.
see below code, currently C# 10.0 (Preview 5)

```
const string WEB_API_ROOT = "/private/WebApi/";
const string WEB_API_PROJECT = $"{WEB_API_ROOT}project.json";
```

you can also checkout docs from official site [What's new in C# 10.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10)

Answer (score 1):

A constant used with `string.Format` would, by its nature, be intended to work with a specific number of arguments which each have a predetermined meaning.

In other words, if you create this constant:

```
const string FooFormat = "Foo named '{0}' was created on {1}.";
```

Then in order to use it you must have two arguments which are probably supposed to be a `string` and a `DateTime`.

So even before string interpolation we were in a sense using the constant as a function. In other words, instead of separating the constant, it might have made more sense to put it in a function instead, like this:

```
string FormatFooDescription(string fooName, DateTime createdDate) =>
    string.Format("Foo named '{0}' was created on {1}.", fooName, createdDate);
```

It's still the same thing, except that the constant (string literal) is now located with the function and arguments that use it. They might as well be together, because the format string is useless for any other purpose. What's more, now you can see the intent of the arguments that are applied to the format string.

When we look at it that way, the similar use of string interpolation becomes obvious:

```
string FormatFooDescription(string fooName, DateTime createdDate) =>
    $"Foo named '{fooName}' was created on {createdDate}.";
```

What if we have multiple format strings and we want to choose a particular one at runtime?

Instead of selecting which string to use, we could select a function:

```
delegate string FooDescriptionFunction(string fooName, DateTime createdDate);
```

Then we could declare implementations like this:

```
static FooDescriptionFunction FormatFoo { get; } = (fooName, createdDate) => 
    $"Foo named '{fooName}' was created on {createdDate}.";
```

Or, better yet:

```
delegate string FooDescriptionFunction(Foo foo);

static FooDescriptionFunction FormatFoo { get; } = (foo) => 
    $"Foo named '{foo.Name}' was created on {foo.CreatedDate}.";
}
```