# How compiler handles string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I am using string interpolation for a method attribute like -

```
const string User = "SomeUser";
const string Admin = "Admin";
.
.
.
[Authorize(Roles = $"{User},{Admin}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
```

But Visual Studio gives an error -

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

When I try "+" for string concatenation it works

```
[Authorize(Roles = User + "," + Admin)]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
```

Even if I replace `","` with `','` it gives the same error.

I wonder how the compiler is handling string interpolation?

Comment: String interpolation is just syntactic sugar for a call to `string.Format`, which is not a `constexpr`, and attribute arguments need to be `constexpr`s. There are numerous proposals in the C# language repo regarding changing this behaviour to transform `string.Format` to a `constexpr` in certain cases like these, e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/384

Answer (score 1):

string interpolation is converted to `string.Format` which isn't a compile time constant as it requires
kindly review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451921/why-does-string-interpolation-is-not-working-with-const-strings) for more information